# Is there any way to hide my email when deciding to become a dev on the raspberry pi store?

Tags: python, pi-store

I think that I will have much more excitement creating python programs if I am a dev on the Pi store.  I also do not want to share my email. Is there any way for me to hide my email as a dev, or should I create a new email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just get a disposable email and sign up. [Mailinator](http://mailinator.com/) seems an OK provider.

Answer (score 2):

You could just set up an email account specifically for it?